# I want to show/hide two divs depending on choosing from drop down list , but my script doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to show/hide two divs depending on choosing from drop down list , but my script doesn't work ,

this is my code in view , I tried two scripts but they didn't work

```
               <div class="pages_inner_content pages_inner_over">
               <div class="title_page_start">
               <div class="right_title adv_tite">
                 <h2> إدارة المحتوى </h2><br />
                 <h2><span> الرئيسيه  </span></h2>
              </div>
              </div><!--title_page_start-->
              <div class="bread_cramb">
    <h3> إدارة المحتوى   <span class="span_last"> الرئيسيه </span>
    <select id="choosen">
<option value="showPlace" selected>مكان العرض</option>
    <option value="English">الانجليزيه</option>
    <option value="Arabic">العربيه</option>
  </select> </h3>
</div>  <!--bread_cramb-->
<div class="block_in_adv pages_inner_over" style="margin-bottom:1000px">
    <div class="block_brea">
        <h3 class="acds">الرئيسيه</h3>
        <div class="left_bread left_bread_tube left_bread_tube_con">
            <ul class="links_bread links_buttons">

                <li class="exit">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index")">خروج</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--block_brea-->
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="table_adv_show">
        <div class="row_first color_row">
            <div class="cols_con_1">
            </div>
            <div class="cols_con_2">النص</div>
            <div class="col_9">التعديل </div>
        </div><!--main_row_opi-->
        <div id="divEnglish">
            <ul class="list_pages_web sortable list" id="itemContainer">

                <li class="pages_inner_over">
                    <div class="block_row_table">
                        <div class="main_row_opi_res ">
                            <div class="cols_con_1"> </div>
                            <div class="cols_con_2">العنوان</div>
                            @*<div class="cols_con_3"></div>*@
                            <div class="col_9">التعديل </div>
                        </div><!--main_row_opi-->
                        <div class="main_row_opi">
                            <div class="cols_con_1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="cols_con_2">نظام العائله التفاعلي</div>
                            <div class="col_9">
                                <a href="/IWS/ArHomeEdit" title="edit"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--main_row_opi-->
                    </div><!--main_row_opi-->

                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div id="divArabic">
            <ul class="list_pages_web sortable list" id="itemContainer">

                <li class="pages_inner_over">
                    <div class="block_row_table">
                        <div class="main_row_opi_res ">
                            <div class="cols_con_1"> </div>
                            <div class="cols_con_2">العنوان</div>
                            @*<div class="cols_con_3"></div>*@
                            <div class="col_9">التعديل </div>
                        </div><!--main_row_opi-->

                    </div><!--main_row_opi-->
                    <div class="main_row_opi">
                        <div class="main_row_opi">
                            <div class="cols_con_1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="cols_con_2">Interactive family system</div>
                            <div class="col_9">
                                <a href="/IWS/EnHomeEdit" title="edit"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/*block_row_table*/-->
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        </div><!--table_adv_show-->
</div><!--block_in_adv-->
</div><!--pages_inner_content-->

<script>
//$(function () {
//    $('#divEnglish').hide();
//    $('#divArabic').hide();
//    $('#LangSel').change(function () {
//        if ($('#LangSel').val() == 'English') {
//            $('#divEnglish').show();
//        } else if ($('#LangSel').val() == 'Arabic') {
//            $('#divArabic').hide();
//        }
//    });
//});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#divEnglish").hide();
    $("#divArabic").hide();

    $("#choosen").change(function () {
        if ($("#choosen").selected().val == "English") {
            alert("Hi English");

            //$("#divEnglish").show();
            //$("#divArabic").hide();
        }
        else if ($("#choosen").val() == "Arabic") {
            alert("اهلا بالعربي");

            //$("#divArabic").show();
            //$("#divEnglish").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#divEnglish").hide();
            $("#divArabic").hide();
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

what is the wrong in my script ?? , is there any way to do the request ??

Comment: It looks like your if is doing two different ways of getting the value, the first being invalid without the () on val.  Also, since you are in a change handler for the select you could just do `this.value` or `$(this).val()` to get the English or Arabic value.

Comment: thank u , now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in view the is some Editing :

```
      <select onchange="getval(this);">
            <option value="1">مكان العرض</option>
            <option value="E">English</option>
            <option value="A">Arabic</option>
        </select>
```

and the two divs will be like this:
                      
                       
                      
                       
and the script will be :
                      
        function getval(myValue) {

```
    if (myValue.value == "E")
    {
        $("#divEnglish").show();
        $("#divArabic").hide();
    }
    else if (myValue.value == "A")
    {
        $("#divArabic").show();
        $("#divEnglish").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#divArabic").hide();
        $("#divEnglish").hide();
    }
}
```

now it works